# Android Hilt inheritance with ViewModel, how to make child with empty constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Let's suppose I have a basic ViewModel class:

```
@HiltViewModel
open class BaseViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val firebaseCrashlytics: FirebaseCrashlytics
): ViewModel() {

}
```

Is there a way how to extend the BaseViewModel without passing the arguments to the constructor?

```
@HiltViewModel
class ChildViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val firebaseCrashlytics: FirebaseCrashlytics
) : BaseViewModel(firebaseAuth, firebaseCrashlytics) {

}
```

I found one related question but unfortunately without any answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117680/hilt-field-injection-in-the-super-fragment-or-viewmodel)

Comment: No I don't think you, because a constructor is still a constructor, dagger hilt can't do anything in order to change this. But you can remove `@HiltViewModel` and `@Inject` from your base class and make it abstract.

Comment: Just do Field Injection for `FirebaseAuth` and `FirebaseCrashlytics` in `BaseViewModel` instead of constructor injection. But remember there are downsides for Field Injection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it